# Github - automatically merge base branch into pull request?

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

Does Github provide a facility to automatically merge the *base* branch into a pull request? In a development team following a gitflow branching workflow, it would be useful to see what the result of "Merge Pull Request" is in the **PR diff**.

Example: Two feature branches were created based on master at the same time.

- Branch1: committed a change to readme and it's pulled into master via
  PR.
- Branch2: committed a change to readme, raised a pull request
  (PR#3), and the diff doesn't show the line that was added with the
  branch1 pull request.

https://github.com/jparmstrong/gittest/pull/3

Comment: There was a feature added that requires the branch to be up to date and to do this via UI if there aren't conflicts https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks

Answer (score -2):

> Does Github provide a facility to automatically merge the base branch into a pull request?

There cannot be one. Automatical merges are generally impossible because nobody would be there to resolve the conflicts.

To achieve what you want: Ask your developers/contributers to rebase branch2 on the current master first before sending the PR...

Comment: Thanks AnoE, but we're assuming developers always do the right thing. In the scenario where they forget to rebase before pushing the branch, I'd like to be able to see the conflict on the pull request. Github partically implemented but reduce it to a true/false/null value.  https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#response-1